# Why is renderUI not working in custom modal?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with a modal that is displayed when I click on a button. I couldn't use `shiny::modalDialog()` so I adapted [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp) from W3schools.

Here's what it looks like:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css")
  ),
  useShinyjs(), 
  actionButton("modal", "open modal"),
  div(
    id = "my_modal",
    class = "w3-modal",
    div(
      class = "w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom",
      div(
        class = "w3-container w3-padding",
        actionButton("generate_ui", "generate UI"),
        uiOutput("new_ui"),
        div(
          class="w3-container w3-padding",
          tags$button(class="w3-button w3-right w3-white w3-border",
                      onclick="document.getElementById('my_modal').style.display='none'",
                      "Close")
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  
  tags$script(
    HTML( '// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("my_modal");

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}')
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  shinyjs::onclick(
    "modal",
    shinyjs::runjs(
      "document.getElementById('my_modal').style.display='block'"
    )
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$generate_ui, {
    print("hello from modal")
    output$new_ui <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        p("This is the new UI")
      )
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the modal, I have a button that is supposed to render some text. However, when I click on the button, nothing is rendered. This is not a problem with `observeEvent()` because the statement in `print()` is correctly displayed in the RStudio console.

Why is `renderUI()` not working in this situation?

Also asked on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-is-renderui-not-working-in-custom-modal/113059)

Comment: I think in this example the issue is somewhere with the stylesheet you linked at the top. What is the problem with modalDialog? Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039694/15492642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because render events are controlled by Javascripts in Shiny. By default, if the dynamic rendering UI is hidden, in your case is the `uiOutput` element, Shiny would not render it unless it is visible. The term visible here is more than just toggle the css display state to be `block`. It needs to hear instructions from javascript listeners. In this case, it explicitly listens to a `"shown"` type of listener. So the way to solve it is in addition to change the display, you also need to trigger the `shown` event.

Method 1, just use {shinyjs} package, the easiest way

```r
shinyjs::onclick(
    "modal", 
    shinyjs::show("my_modal")
)
```

Method 2, use jquery, which is what behind {shinyjs}

```r
shinyjs::onclick(
    "modal", 
    shinyjs::runjs("$('#my_modal').show(); $('#new_ui').trigger('shown');")
)
```

Full code

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css")
    ),
    useShinyjs(), 
    actionButton("modal", "open modal"),
    div(
        id = "my_modal",
        class = "w3-modal",
        div(
            class = "w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom",
            div(
                class = "w3-container w3-padding",
                actionButton("generate_ui", "generate UI"),
                uiOutput("new_ui"),
                div(
                    class="w3-container w3-padding",
                    tags$button(class="w3-button w3-right w3-white w3-border",
                                onclick="document.getElementById('my_modal').style.display='none'",
                                "Close")
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    
    tags$script(
        HTML( '// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("my_modal");

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}')
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    
    shinyjs::onclick(
        "modal", 
        # shinyjs::runjs("$('#my_modal').show(); $('#new_ui').trigger('shown');")
        shinyjs::show("my_modal")
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$generate_ui, {
        print("hello from modal")
        output$new_ui <- renderUI({
            tagList(
                p("This is the new UI")
            )
        })
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think method 3 is not working, the new UI is not created, but thanks for the other alternatives

Comment: You are right, it turns out it is not working and I haven't found a good way to use native js to do this. I deleted the method